# check if a string is contained in a text file of words in java

Tags: java, arraylist, io, string-comparison

I have a text file (collection of all valid english words) from a github project that looks like this [words.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words.txt)

My text file is under the `resources` folder in my project.

I have also a list of rows obtained from a table in mysql.
What i'm trying to do is to check if all the words in a every row are valid english words, that's why I compare each row with the words contained in my file.

This what i've tried so far :

```
 public static void englishCheck(List<String> rows) throws IOException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    int lenght, occurancy = 0;
    for ( String row : rows ){

       File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("words.txt").getFile());


       lenght = 0;

       if ( !row.isEmpty()  ){
           System.out.println("the row : "+row);
           String[] tokens = row.split("\\W+");
           lenght = tokens.length;
           for (String token : tokens) {

               occurancy = 0;
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

               String line;
               while ((line = br.readLine()) != null ){


                   if ((line.trim().toLowerCase()).equals(token.trim().toLowerCase())){
                       occurancy ++ ;

                   }
                   if (occurancy == lenght ){ System.out.println(" this is english "+row);break;}

               }

           }





       }

   }
}
```

this works only for the very first rows, after that my method loops over the rows only displaying them and ignores the comparison, I would like to know why this isn't working for my set of rows, It works also if I predefined my list like this  `List<String> raws = Arrays.asList(raw1, raw2, raw3 )` and so on

Comment: Super bad idea: you create a n * m double loop here. You absolutely do **not** want to read that file again and again for each of your words.

Comment: @DevRj what is the format of data in /words.txt?? it is line by line of in the same line , give a sample

Comment: Hint: when you *edit* your source code ... make sure to properly format it.

Comment: @GhostCat maybe it's a bad idea and maybe you can provide a way to verify if every word in a row is contained in that file, and a way to read that file into memory at once since it's your suggestion. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read `words.txt` file, convert words into lower case, then put words into `HashSet`.

Use the `boolean contains(Object o)` or `boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c);` methods to compare each word. 
The time was **O(n)**.

> **TIP： Do not read file in every loop. Reading file is very very slow.**

```
ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("words.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
List<String> wordList = new LinkedList<String>(); // You do not know word count, LinkedList is a better way.
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  String[] words = line.toLowerCase().split("\\W+");
  wordList.addAll(Arrays.asList(words));
}
Set<String> wordSet = new HashSet<String>(wordList.size());
wordSet.addAll(wordList);


// then you can use the wordSet to check. 
// You shold convert the tokens to lower case.
String[] tokens = row.toLowerCase().split("\\W+");
wordSet.containsAll(Arrays.asList(tokens));
```

Comment: Helpful answer just some edits like you can directly pass some values , instead of `Set<String> wordSet = new HashSet<String>(wordList.size());
wordSet.addAll(wordList);` you can simply do this : `Set<String> wordSet = new HashSet<String>(wordList);`, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method [List#containsAll(Collection)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-)

> Returns true if this list contains all of the elements of the
>   specified collection.

lets assume you have both list flled **myListFromRessources**  and **myListFromRessources** then you can do:

```
List<String> myListFromRessources = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
List<String> myListFromRessources = Arrays.asList("D", "B");

boolean myInter = myListFromRessources.containsAll(myListFromSQL);
System.out.println(myInter);
myListFromSQL = Arrays.asList("D", "B", "Y");
myInter = myListFromRessources.containsAll(myListFromSQL);
System.out.println(myInter);
```

Comment: You also want to add something about maybe reading that file into memory at once.

Comment: not really, that is why I wrote: ***"lets assume you have both list filled"***...  am assuming OP knows how to do that since he doesnt refer any issue about it in the code...

Comment: my file is a set of English words that are downloaded from a github project, and I don't have a clear idea about what my SQL table contains, it may contain some nonsense words  (`row = "ghsjgsdh hg.hg"`) or half English words row = "half valid English sentence hkdojgsv hdh") or a valid one row = "valid English sentence"`, I can't seem to understand how your suggestion is suitable for my case

Comment: I assume the second `myListFromRessources` was mean to be `myListFromSQL` (in both your explanation and in the code).

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work is that `occurancy` can never be anything other than 0 or 1. You can see that by following the logic or going through a debugger.

If your words.txt file is not too large, and you have enough RAM available, you can speed up processing by reading the words.txt file into memory at the start. Also, you only ever need to call toLowerCase() once, instead of every time you compare. However, be careful with locales. The following code should work as long as you haven't got any non-English characters such as a German eszett or a Greek sigma.

```
public static void englishCheck(List<String> rows) throws IOException {
    final URI wordsUri;
    try {
        wordsUri = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("words.txt").toURI();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e); // can never happen
    }

    final Set<String> words = Files.lines(Paths.get(wordsUri))
            .map(String::toLowerCase)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    for (String row: rows)
        if (!row.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("the row : " + row);
            String[] tokens = row.toLowerCase().split("\\W+");
            if (words.containsAll(Arrays.asList(tokens)))
                System.out.println(" this is english " + row);
        }
}
```